# How to find Broken Links using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm facing an issue with finding the broken links on the webpage. I'm using **RequestsLibrary** for the same. Right now I'm able to find all the links but now able to verify them against the response code.

```
Get All Link Tests
    [Tags]    Regression
    [Setup]    Log To Console    Test for total links present on landing page started...
    ${base_url}=    Get Base Url
    open browser  about:blank  ${browser}
    go to  ${base_url}

    ${ALL_LINKS_COUNT}  get element count  xpath://a
    log to console  ${ALL_LINKS_COUNT}

    @{LINK_ITEMS}  create list
    : FOR  ${index}  IN RANGE  1  ${ALL_LINKS_COUNT}+1
    \  log  ${index}
    \  ${link_text}  get text  xpath:(//a)[${index}]
    \  ${href}  Get Element Attribute  xpath:(//a)[${index}]  href
    \  log  ${link_text}
    \  log to console  ("The link text is "${link_text}" & href is "${href}" ${INDEX})
    \  ${link_length}  Get Length  ${link_text}
    \  Run Keyword If  ${linklength}>1  Append To List  ${LinkItems}  ${href}
    Log Many  ${LINK_ITEMS}
    Remove Values From List  ${href}  javascript:void(0)  \#
    ${link_items_length}  Get Length  ${LINK_ITEMS}
    @{errors_msg}    Create List
    : FOR  ${index}  IN RANGE  ${link_items_length}
    \  ${resp}  Get Request  ${LINK_ITEMS[${index}]}
    \  ${code}  Run Keyword And Return Status  Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}  200
    \  Run Keyword Unless  ${code}  Append To List  ${errors_msg}  error :${LINK_ITEMS[${index}]} | ${resp.status_code}
    ${check}  Run Keyword And Return Status  Lists Should Be Equal  ${errors_msg}  ${EMPTY}
    Run Keyword Unless  ${check}  Fail  Link \ assertion Failed with msg:\n@{errors_msg}
```

The error that I'm getting right now is **"RequestsLibrary.Get Request** expected 2 to 7 arguments, got 1.**"**
I've tried doing it with **create session** also, but then it fails with a message **"**Link  assertion Failed with msg:
[]**"**

Answer (score 1):

You need to do that `Create Session` first and then pass the `alias` as the first parameter for `Get Request`. [RequestsLibrary documentation](http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html) says it quite clear.

The other error message shows that you have an empty list in `@{errors_msg}`. I guess you need to pass the index number there.

Comment: I've already tried with **Create Session** and it doesn't work. For the error message part, is it possible to add the index number without knowing the broken link?

Comment: Well, that `alias` parameter is mandatory and that comes from `Create Session` keyword. Check the logs/error message after using `Create Session`.

Comment: Now it's not capturing any link & I've attached the report [link] (https://ibb.co/8DgXHLZ).

Comment: Seems that your `Open Browser` does not go to that crediwatch.org page you should go, right? Even if you have a `RequestLibrary` session with the same site doesn't mean that that `SeleniumLibrary` keyword can access that site. So you have to Open Browser to that same site first as well. Then you might get some a tags, checked that there should be 73 of them.

Comment: True and I tried doing it with just **requests** library it worked but in the end, it failed again while checking for the error message. [link](https://ibb.co/K6NFXG4). Also, I thought of doing it another way as well i.e creating a custom library and writing the code for the same and calling that library into the scripts. In the settings, I can import it in **Resource** but I don't know which keyword should I use in the Test Case part...

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it works. However, now it works only for links starting with https://www.crediwatch.com. Also, the href list contains some `mailto` links which should be filtered out.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
Library    RequestsLibrary
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    String
Test Setup    Open Browser    ${BASE_URL}
Test Teardown    Close Browser


*** Variables ***
${BASE_URL}    https://www.crediwatch.com

*** Test Cases ***
Broken links test
    ${element_list}=     get webelements     xpath=//a[@href]
    ${href_list}=  Evaluate  [item.get_attribute('href') for item in $element_list]
    Log    ${href_list}

    Create Session    testing    ${BASE_URL}
    FOR    ${element_href}    IN    @{href_list}
        ${uri}=    Remove String    ${element_href}    ${BASE_URL}
        ${contains_base_url}=    Evaluate     "${BASE_URL}" in "${element_href}"
        ${response}=    Run Keyword If    ${contains_base_url}    Get Request    testing    ${uri}
        Run Keyword If    ${contains_base_url}    Should Be Equal As Strings     ${response.status_code}    200
    END
```