# Availability of any keyword(in selenium2library) to extract the source code of a webpage

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am a new user of Robot Framework and have been using it to automate GUI Testing on a webpage.

My task is to automate the process of opening a link in a browser and click on all possible hyperlinks present in the webpage and check if they are working as expected or not (i.e) if they are redirecting me to the appropriate page.
To do this, I want to know if there is a keyword that would obtain the names of all the hyperlinks present in the webpage (or) if there is a keyword or method which would recognize all the hyperlinks and click on them.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and make it way more clear as to what you are asking, and whats the issue.

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly I just rephrased the question. Hope this has made it more understandable. Thank you!

Comment: I also suggest linking some code in and showing how you have attempted the problem :) i upvote your edit. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I'll link my code for better understanding.

Comment: There was a similar question just a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58505397/how-to-find-broken-links-using-robot-framework/58520711#58520711

Answer (score 1):

In SeleniumLibrary, there is a keyword [Get All Links](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20All%20Links). Use it to get a list of all links in the page, and iterate over the list of links. Something like this (not tested):

```
${listOfLinks} =     Get All Links
:FOR    ${link}    IN    @{listOfLinks}
\       Click Element     ${link}
```

Or if you want to amuse yourself, use the [Get Source](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Source) keyword to obtain the HTML and then by using the [XML Library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html) search for the links that you need (Parse XML, Get Elements and so on). :)