# How to check the links are broken for a particular xpath using robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have xxx url, where
its has A element=== Links, B element===Links,
I want to validate Links are broken under A element,
I need to do under Robot framework please help

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
Library    RequestsLibrary
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    String
Test Setup    Open Browser    ${BASE_URL}
Test Teardown    Close Browser


*** Variables ***
${BASE_URL}    https://www.crediwatch.com

*** Test Cases ***
Broken links test
    ${element_list}=     get webelements     xpath=//a[@href]
    ${href_list}=  Evaluate  [item.get_attribute('href') for item in $element_list]
    Log    ${href_list}

    Create Session    testing    ${BASE_URL}
    FOR    ${element_href}    IN    @{href_list}
        ${uri}=    Remove String    ${element_href}    ${BASE_URL}
        ${contains_base_url}=    Evaluate     "${BASE_URL}" in "${element_href}"
        ${response}=    Run Keyword If    ${contains_base_url}    Get Request    testing    ${uri}
        Run Keyword If    ${contains_base_url}    Should Be Equal As Strings     ${response.status_code}    200
    END
```

Comment: Show what you've already tried

Comment: I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58505397/how-to-find-broken-links-using-robot-framework not sure whether this is correct

Comment: I have added the code , i am new to this can you please explain this?